# PHP file get content - only specific part of the text

Tags: php

Hi just need to solve this php issue

What I need is to get only specific part of the text that I get from remote server. So remote server gives me this kind of content

......":"http://xxxxxxxx.com?source=yyyyy&service=zzzzz&token=47baiufbweiwrwrqwr21","...........

And I need to get back only this part: token=47baiufbweiwrwrqwr21

thank for help

Comment: So did you try something ? you can use explode for example.

Comment: [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)? [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)? We're not a code-writing service. You're expected to try something on your own.

Answer (score 0):

Use parse_url() and preg_match()

```
$url = 'http://xxxxxxxx.com?source=yyyyy&service=zzzzz&token=47baiufbweiwrwrqwr21';

$query = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
         preg_match('/token=([a-z0-9]+)/i', $query, $token);

echo $token[1];
```

parse_url() returns the Components of an URL.
You want to have a specific Query-Parameter, so you use the PHP_URL_QUERY-Component. After this you extract the token with a Regular Expression that searches for the Parameter-Name "token" followed by a "=". Then you catch all characters you want (a-z and 0-9). You set the i-Delimiter for a caseinsensitive Search. $token[1] returns the Match within the Subpattern (Brackets).

And if you get the URL from a File you can read it into a String using file_get_contents().

Answer (score 0):

You can use substr and stripos 
This will make sure you get the correct part even if the variables are in a different order and is not case sensitive.

https://3v4l.org/q35f0

```
$url = 'http://xxxxxxxx.com?source=yyyyy&token=47baiufbweiwrwrqwr21&service=zzzzz';

$pos = stripos($url, "token");
$pos2 = stripos($url, "&", $pos);

If($pos2 > 0){
    Echo substr($url, $pos, $pos2-$pos);
}Else{
    Echo substr($url, $pos);
}
```

Edit sorry my phone autocorrected my stripos to strpos. Funny how my phone is starting to learn php.